# Monotouch / Xamarin changing the table row height for iPad applications

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am having trouble figuring out how to change the `rowHeight` for the tables in my `Xamarin` iPad application. Previously I've worked on iPhone apps and adjusting the size of the rows were as simple as calling the following in the `TableSource` Class:

```
public override float GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return 95f;
        }
```

However, I'm finding out that this is not being called in the iPad app. Is there another method I should be calling or am I just going about this completely wrong?

Comment: Not familiar with Xamarin, but in Objective-C, you'd just set the table view's `rowHeight` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are doing it correctly by overriding GetHeightForRow, but if its not changing it I'd suggest checking your ViewDidLoad method on the controller to make sure it's setting the tableview source to your custom tableSource class.

For example, in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
_tableview.Source = new TableSource();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just easy way. Create your custom TV:

```
public class CustomTableViewStyle : UITableView
    {
        public CustomTableViewStyle (System.Drawing.RectangleF frame)
        {
            Initialize (frame);
        }

        void Initialize (System.Drawing.RectangleF frame)
        {
            Frame = frame;
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
            ScrollEnabled = true;
            SectionFooterHeight = 0;
            AllowsSelection = true;
            AllowsMultipleSelection = false;
            SeparatorColor = UIColor.FromRGB (239, 243, 243);
            RowHeight = 210;  <-- // Your table row height!
            SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
            DelaysContentTouches = true;
            CanCancelContentTouches = true;

        }

    }
```

If you do not want to create your own just change the property on your table `RowHeight`.
And dont forget create a class for TableView or Id in storyboard.